# Redeploy Azure VM and Retain Static IP

Tags: azure

I have an IP address configured for my Azure VM that I don't want to lose, because it's configured in DNS. However I would like to redeploy the server due to some issues.

Is there a way to re-deploy an Azure VM and keep the same IP as before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A re-deploy will keep the IP. The IP is bound to your NIC and the OS is bound to the Disk. You would need to delete the NIC resource separately to the VM to lose your IP configs.

You can use the re-deploy feature on the VM or even delete the VM then recreate in portal and just select the existing resources such as NIC and Disk.